# Prove that for $1\leq p\leq 2$ and $0<b<a$, $(a+b)^p+(a-b)^p\geq 2a^p+p(p-1)a^{p-2}b^2$.

Tags: derivatives, inequality, jensen-inequality

To start this one, my idea is dividing both side by $a^p$, then the question will become $(1+x)^p+(1-x)^p\geq 2+p(p-1)x^2$. So we need to check $f(x)=(1+x)^p+(1-x)^p- 2-p(p-1)x^2\geq 0$ on $x\in(0,1)$ for all $p\in[1,2]$. It's clear that it's true as $p=1,2$. And for $p\in(0,1)$, I try to take first and second derivative, but the case becomes very complicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not complicated:
$$f''(x)=p(p-1)((1+x)^{p-2}+(1-x)^{p-2}-2)\geq0$$ by Jensen.

Can you end it now?

I used the following Jensen:
$$\frac{(1+x)^{p-2}+(1-x)^{p-2}}{2}\geq\left(\frac{1+x+1-x}{2}\right)^{p-2}=1.$$

Comment: I think $(1+x)^{p-2}+(1-x)^{p-2}\geq 2^{2-p}$ not 2.

Comment: @Irene Yu $\frac{(1+x)^{p-2}+(1-x)^{p-2}}{2}\geq\left(\frac{1+x+1-x}{2}\right)^{p-2}=1.$

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg But $p\in[1,2]$, which means $p-2\leq 0$. And I think we need to show $f''\leq 0$ to achieve the  conclusion.

Comment: @Irene Yu $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ is a convex function for $\alpha<0$. Jensen says $\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}\geq f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right).$

Comment: Right, I see it now. So we only left to check $f'(x)\geq 0$ at $x=0$.